# Subst drive & folder

Tags: windows, command-line, path, cmd, subst

Can I use windows command `subst` to map a drive *& folder* to another location?

I want to map say the **temp** folder

`c:\foo\bar\temp`

to

`e:\buildserver\dev`

I can easily map the `temp` directory to `e:` using

`subst e: c:\foo\bar\temp`

But how can I also add the path folding the drive `\buildserver\dev`

Comment: What is meant to happen if something accesses `E:\buildserver` if you've managed to do this?

Comment: The build server produces `.pdb` files that point to the server path which is `e:\buildserver\dev`. The copy of the code base on my local machine is at a different path `c:\foo\bar\dev` for example. So I need to create an `e:` drive with the folder names after pointing to my local drive `c:\foo\bar\dev`. Hope that makes sense @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: Note that `subst` is legacy technology.  Avoid it if at all possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a directory junction like so:

```
mklink /J c:\foo\bar\temp\ e:\buildserver\dev\
```

Answer (score -1):

On Windows 10 and Windows 7, instead of subst e: c:\foo\bar\temp

NET USE E: "c:\foo\bar\temp"

This sticks across a reboot.

Comment: This tells me 
`System error 67 has occurred.
The network name cannot be found.`

Comment: This is not correct. For one, this needs to use a network path (e.g. UNC path like `\\localhost\C$\foo`). Also, this is _not_ persistent across reboots. To make it persistent, use the `/PERSISTENT:YES` flag. However, the approach in general is not a good solution to the issue in the OP. Using a _junction_ as suggested by @CyberDude or a _symbolic directory link_ is preferable. For more information, see [“directory junction” vs “directory symbolic link”](https://superuser.com/questions/343074/directory-junction-vs-directory-symbolic-link).